# Android: Why 'invalid' region is called so?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is an extension of the question [What is invalid region in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359356/what-is-invalid-region-in-android#)

What is the criterion for a region to become 'valid'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Invalid* means this region contains outdated information and it has to be redrawn during the next `View.draw()` call.

You can invalidate any region by calling `View.invalidate(Rect rect)` method. This method makes supplied rectangle area *invalid*, so that during the next `draw()` frame, view will have to redraw that area. Once redrawn (right after `View.draw()` call) the region becomes *valid* again.

Calling `View.invalidate()` makes whole view area *invalid*. This is also a trigger for Android to call `View.draw()` method. It will schedule this draw-request and execute as soon as possible.

Comment: Nice question and answer. There is `File> Invalidate Caches / Restart...` button in Android Studio, and the same logic applies I believe - updating old caches, just like `View.invalidate()` updates old views.